# How do I save and load BatchNormalization Layer in this Tensorflow model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tf.keras, keras-layer

I am trying to save a model and then load it later to make some predictions; what happens is that the accuracy of the model after training is `95%+`, but when I save it and then load it, the accuracy drops to nearly `10%` on the **same** dataset.

To reproduce this erroneous result, you can run [this](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1wy3nNtRo-JEmFtFKi2IqNfrDtgy7cI8-?usp=sharing) really small notebook.

The model is defined as follows:

```
model_scratch_auto = models.Sequential()
model_scratch_auto.add(Flatten(input_shape=(28,28)))
model_scratch_auto.add(Dense(80, activation='relu'))
model_scratch_auto.add(Dense(100, activation='relu'))
model_scratch_auto.add(Dense(120, activation='relu'))
model_scratch_auto.add(Dense(100, activation='relu'))
auto_srelu=AutoSRELU()
model_scratch_auto.add(auto_srelu)
model_scratch_auto.add(Dense(120, activation='relu'))
model_scratch_auto.add(auto_srelu)
model_scratch_auto.add(BatchNormalization())
model_scratch_auto.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))
model_scratch_auto.compile(optimizer = tf.optimizers.Adam(),loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['acc',f1_m,precision_m, recall_m])

model_scratch_auto.fit(X_train, y_train , batch_size=64, epochs=5, validation_data=(X_test, y_test),verbose=1)
```

Where the custom layer, `AutoSRELU` is defined as follows:

```
initializer0 = keras.initializers.RandomUniform(minval = -1, maxval =1)
initializer1 = keras.initializers.RandomUniform(minval = 0.5, maxval =3)

 
class MinMaxConstraint(keras.constraints.Constraint):
    def __init__(self, minval, maxval):
        self.minval = tf.constant(minval ,dtype='float32')
        self.maxval = tf.constant(maxval ,dtype='float32')
    def __call__(self, w):
        tf.cond(tf.greater(self.minval,w)
                , lambda: w + (self.minval - w)
                , lambda: tf.cond(tf.greater(w,self.maxval)
                                  , lambda: w - (w - self.maxval)
                                  , lambda: w))
    def get_config(self):
        return {'Lower Bound': self.minval, 'Upper Bound':self.maxval}
 
 

def srelu(inputs, k1, k2):
    cond1 = tf.cast(tf.math.less(inputs, 0.0), tf.float32)
    cond2 = tf.cast(tf.math.greater_equal(inputs, 0.0), tf.float32)
    a = tf.math.multiply(cond1, tf.add(k1,tf.multiply(0.3, inputs)))
    b = tf.math.multiply(cond2, tf.add(k1,tf.multiply(k2, inputs)))
    outputs = a + b
    return outputs
    

class AutoSRELU(keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, trainable = True, **kwargs):
        super(AutoSRELU, self).__init__()
        self.k1 = self.add_weight(name='k', shape = (), initializer=initializer0, trainable=trainable)#, constraint=keras.constraints.NonNeg())
        self.k2 = self.add_weight(name='n', shape = (), initializer=initializer1, trainable=trainable)#, constraint=MinMaxConstraint(1,10))
    def call(self, inputs):
        return srelu(inputs, self.k1, self.k2)
```

Then I evaluate the model performance using the `evaluate()` function and get the following result:

```
model_scratch_auto.evaluate(X_train, y_train)
```

*Output:*

```
1875/1875 [==============================] - 4s 2ms/step - loss: 0.0517 - acc: 0.9834 - f1_m: 0.9836 - precision_m: 0.9851 - recall_m: 0.9823
[0.05167238786816597,
 0.9834166765213013,
 0.983639121055603,
 0.9850572943687439,
 0.9822666645050049]
```

Then I save the model as:

```
model_scratch_auto.save('test_model.h5')
```

And when I load the same model by setting the dependencies as follows:

```
dependencies = {
     'f1_m': f1_m,
     'precision_m': precision_m,
     'recall_m': recall_m,
     'AutoSRELU': AutoSRELU
}

test_model = models.load_model('test_model.h5', custom_objects=dependencies)
```

And when I evaluate this model on the same dataset, I get the following result:

```
test_model.evaluate(X_train, y_train)
```

*Output:*

```
1875/1875 [==============================] - 2s 1ms/step - loss: 8.5696 - acc: 0.1047 - f1_m: 0.1047 - precision_m: 0.1047 - recall_m: 0.1047
[8.569587707519531,
 0.10468333214521408,
 0.10468332469463348,
 0.10468333214521408,
 0.10468333214521408]
```

As you can see, saving the same model and evaluating it on the same dataset **significantly** reduces the performance. I tried many things to see why this must be happening and I found out that removing `BatchNormalization()` and `AutoSRELU` corrected the issue, but I can't seem to understand why they are causing this issue. To see if the `RandomUniform` function was maybe causing some problems, I re-ran the loading part along with the class definition multiple times to see if there was some randomness in the loaded model but that was returning an identical worse result every time. I then saw that removing the batch normalization layer gave almost identical results.

So I was able to narrow down the problem to `BatchNormalization` `AutoSRELU` but I can't understand how to correct it. How do I save and load the model correctly so that it gives the same results?

Comment: Take a look at this: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/save_and_load It should so what you want.

Comment: What version of Tensorflow are you running?

Comment: I had updated TensorFlow to 2.6.0 recently and it's giving the same results, you can also run this on Colab using the link I've mentioned in the question, that is also giving the same results

Answer (score 1):

Replace the saving of the model from Keras to TF.

```
tf.keras.models.save_model(model_scratch_auto, "test_model")
```

I did it in your notebook and it worked :)

```
model_scratch_auto.evaluate(X_train, y_train)
1875/1875 [==============================] - 4s 2ms/step - loss: 0.0848 - acc: 0.9747 - f1_m: 0.9749 - precision_m: 0.9781 - recall_m: 0.9718
[0.08477196097373962,
 0.9746833443641663,
 0.9748622179031372,
 0.9780662059783936,
 0.9717833399772644]

test_model.evaluate(X_train, y_train)
1875/1875 [==============================] - 4s 2ms/step - loss: 0.0791 - acc: 0.9821 - f1_m: 0.9822 - precision_m: 0.9827 - recall_m: 0.9817
[0.07907719910144806,
 0.9820666909217834,
 0.9821747541427612,
 0.9827000498771667,
 0.9816666841506958]
```

Comment: Do you mean `test_model`  or  `test_model.h5`?

Comment: No, there are 2 ways of saving the model, using Keras (`model.save()`) and using TensorFlow (`tf.keras.models.save_model()`). So replace the model.save("test_model.h5") with tf.keras.models.save_model(model_scratch_auto, "test_model"). I think the first type (Keras) of saving doesn’t preserve the costume part of the model that why the accuracy was low. But with the other method everything is conserved.